# BitWasp doesn't load CSS and Js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have just installed bitwasp and now i ran into this problem with a php generated html file, it doesnt load the CSS and the javascript because its pointed to the index.php.

Is there some fix in Php or need i to change my Apache server settings

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="open source bitcoin marketplace" />
    <title>Welcome | BitWasp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.0.0.12/BitWasp/index.php/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.0.0.12/BitWasp/index.php/assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://10.0.0.12/BitWasp/index.php/assets/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://10.0.0.12/BitWasp/index.php/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    
</head>
```

Thanks in advance